# Count number of records in child table in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, foreign-keys

I have two classes  with one to many relationship. I want to count the number of records in the child class based on the primary key of the parent class.

Parent table class

```
  public class SystemFamily
{
    public SystemFamily()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        deleteFlag = false;

    }

    public int SystemFamilyID { get; set;}
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } 
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public bool deleteFlag { get; set; }
    public int SystemsCount {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Systems> Systems { get; set; }
    public string SFamilyName
    {
        get
        {
            return FamilyName;
        } 
    }

 }
```

Child table class

```
  public class Systems
{

    public int SystemsID { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set;}
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int SystemFamilyID { get; set; }

    public virtual SystemFamily SystemFamily { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure where the count should be performed. In the view or the controller? So i will post the required code after suggestions.

Thanks in advance!
Vini

**EDIT 1**

```
    public ActionResult Index()

    {
        //List<Systems> systems;
        //var query = db.SystemFamily.Select(c => c.SystemFamilyID).ToList();
        //foreach (var sid in query)
        //{
        //    systems = db.Systems.Select(c => c.SystemFamilyID == sid).ToList();
        //}
        //int count = systems.Count();//Here you will  get count

        //ViewBag.Counts = count; 
        var viewmodel = new Sys_SysFam();
        foreach (var item in db.SystemFamily)
        {
            int id = item.SystemFamilyID;

            //SystemsCount 
            int count = db.Systems.Where(x => x.SystemFamilyID == id).Count();
            item.SystemsCount = count;
        }
        ViewBag.Count = db.SystemFamily.Where(x=>x.deleteFlag==false).Count();
        int count1 =db.Systems.Count();
        ViewBag.SCount = count1;
        return View(db.SystemFamily.Where(x=>x.deleteFlag==false).ToList());
    }
```

This is  the action method where the logic should go I suppose! I am trying with a foreach loop. but it doesnt work it throws exception : *'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'*

But I also have a ViewSystem which returns the systems in a particular family.

ViewSystem

```
    public ActionResult ViewSystem(int? id)
    {
            var viewmodel = new Sys_SysFam();
            ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id;
            if (id != null)
            {
                ViewBag.SystemFamilyID = id.Value;
                var sysFamily = db.SystemFamily.Include(x => x.Systems).FirstOrDefault(x => x.SystemFamilyID == id.Value);
                if (sysFamily != null)
                {
                    viewmodel.Systems = sysFamily.Systems;
                }
            }

            return View(viewmodel);

    }
```

Comment: This kind of logic should go to the controller.

Comment: Are objects of these classes loaded into memory? Or do you need to write a database (or LINQ) query?

Comment: I need to write a LINQ query inorder to count the number of records in the child class pertaining to a particular parent. I can edit the question with my controller.

Comment: The view system uses a ViewModel, but does counting also require the same logic?

Comment: data access should go in seperate layer (DAL),
All the business operations should be done in Business Layer which calls DAL for any data if required. So in this scenario Count can be done in Business Layer or Controller. Controllers should not contain complex business operations.

Comment: i have all the data access in a separate layer.

Comment: ok, from the code snippet posted above it looks like data access is done in Controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to  do this in  Controller

```
public  ActionResult ActionMethordNam()
{
   List<Systems>  systems;
   var query = db.SystemFamily.Select(c=>c.SystemFamilyID).Tolist(); 
   foreach(var sid in query)
   { 
      systems = db.Systems.Select(c=>c.SystemFamilyID == sid).Tolist(); 
   }
   int count=systems.Count();//Here you will  get count

   Viewbag.Counts  = count; 
   return View();
}
```

Retrive count in View By

`@Viewbag.Counts` in .cshtml

```
@Html.TextBox("syscount", (string)ViewBag.Counts)
```

you Can retrieve the value in post Method by pass as  parameter to the post method now you  can save the data to your table by assigning this value to your  Model Property

Comment: But i want this to be in my view that comes with the index Controller.

Comment: Use Viewbag to get values in View

Comment: But i want is a table with the SystemFamily and it s attribute which includes the count for each systemfamily. How do i take all the values in viewbag?

Comment: @Midhun, db.Systems in foreach loop is a bad practice. It leads to Select(N+1).  For each iteration a query will be fired to the DB.

Comment: ToList doesn't work with IQueryable and it shows errors.

Comment: ToList worked. The 'L' in ToList was small. And I did not notice. But still there is build error.Cannot implicitly convert type List<bool> to List><Systems>

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan How do i save this value to the database. it only helps in populating the Index view. But the value is not updated in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var dataList =  db.SystemFamily.Where(x => x.SystemFamilyID == id.Value).SelectMany(s => s.Systems).GroupBy(key => key.SystemFamilyID, sys => new {sys},
               (i, sys) =>
               new SystemsViewModel{
                 System = sys,
                 Count = sys.Count()
               }).ToList();
```

pass the dataList to the View